# Adjusting size of in app screenshot

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am having problem in taking a screenshot with specific area. 
I have a tabbar at the bottom and a toolbar at the top. I would like to take a screenshot of the screen between those two bars. Below is my code. How can i improve my code to crop out the bars?

Thanks

```
CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Iterate over every window from back to front
for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
{
    if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
    {
        // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
        // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        // Center the context around the window's anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
        // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
        // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                              -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                              -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

        // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
        [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

        // Restore the context
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}

// Retrieve the screenshot image
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();




UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(imageSavedToPhotosAlbum: didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);
```

Comment: check this post..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694806/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-part-of-an-apps-window/9696309#9696309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could try cropping out the part you need after creating the final UIImage.

```
CGRect contentRectToCrop = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 392);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], contentRectToCrop);
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds good, but where can i place this code? I tried to put in before the saving method, but seems does not work.

Comment: Try replacing the single line UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); in your code with this block and be sure to pass 'croppedImage' instead of 'image' to the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum method.

Comment: For retina image cropping, you need to add scaling factor to contentRectToCrop

Answer (score 0):

Untested sugestion:

```
imageSize.origin.y+=44; //toolbar size
imageSize.size.height-=88; //tabbar+toolbar size
```